# create a PySpark Schema for a tuple composed of a list and an array

Tags: pyspark, sql-types

Can someone help please and tell me what should be the correct PySpark Schema for the following tuple:

```
([['__label__positif', '__label__négatif', '__label__neutre']], array([[0.60312474, 0.24436191, 0.15254335]]))
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What dataframe structure do you want to get?

Comment: six columns: three columns each containing a label and three columns each containing a double number @cronoik

Comment: What is the output of type(tuple[1])?

Comment: indeed it is a prediction result made by a fasttext model, so to predict the class of each row I must have the above expression as a result for each row, so I have to pass the prediction function in udf , to do this I must specify the schema of the expression below in the  udf function

Comment: the output of the model is : " ([['__label__positif', '__label__négatif', '__label__neutre']], array([[0.60312474, 0.24436191, 0.15254335]])) "

Comment: That is not relevant for me. I want to know what the datatype of the array is. So please tell what the output of `type(outputofModel[1])` is.

Comment: code : print (pred)
print (type (pred))         output : ([['__label__positif', '__label__négatif', '__label__neutre']], array([[0.60214394, 0.24506931, 0.15281674]]))
<class 'tuple'>

Comment: Again, what is `print(type(pred[1]))`?

Comment: oh ok I'm sorry, it  gives this : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the narrated code below:

```py
import numpy as np

#this is the object you got from the fasttext model
pred = ([['__label__positif', '__label__négatif', '__label__neutre']], np.array([[0.60312474, 0.24436191, 0.15254335]]))
print(pred)

#At first we flatten this object to create a list with 6 elements
pred = [item for sublist in pred for subsubiter in sublist for item in subsubiter]
print(pred)

#pyspark doesn't work that well with numpy and therefore we cast the numpy floats to python floats
pred = [x.item() if type(x) == np.float64 else x for x in pred]
print(pred)

l = [tuple(pred)]

columns = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)
df.show()
```

Output:

```py
([['__label__positif', '__label__négatif', '__label__neutre']], array([[0.60312474, 0.24436191, 0.15254335]])) 
['__label__positif', '__label__négatif', '__label__neutre', 0.60312474, 0.24436191, 0.15254335] 
['__label__positif', '__label__négatif', '__label__neutre', 0.60312474, 0.24436191, 0.15254335] 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+ 
|             one|             two|          three|      four|      five|       six| 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+ 
|__label__positif|__label__négatif|__label__neutre|0.60312474|0.24436191|0.15254335| 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+
```